# Como manter o zero a esquerda de uma subtração em java?

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo um código em Java e preciso do valor de uma subtração.

Por exemplo: 98 - 96 = 02. Mas o código só me retorna 2 como resultado final. O que posso fazer para ficar com o 02 como resultado final?

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int num = 98 -96;
      System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das formas é usar o `printf` ao invés do `println`.

Com o `printf` vc consegue configurar os especificadores para acrescentar o 0 na frente.

Por exemplo, para imprimir um número inteiro, vc faria assim:

```java
System.out.printf("%d\n", num); // 2
```

E para acrescentar o 0, seria assim:

```java
System.out.printf("%02d\n", num); // 02
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar a função String.format()

```
String.format("%02d\n", num);
```

Ficaria desta forma:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int num = 98 - 96;
      System.out.println(String.format("%02d\n", num));
    }
}
```